# How to use $this in usort for using class inner function

Tags: php, function, class, this

I have made this function in my class,

```
protected function compareByName($a, $b) {
  return strcmp($a["name"], $b["name"]);
}
usort($a, 'compareByName'); // here I have to use this function name
```

How can we use this function name using `$this` variable

Comment: @deceze, we have to use `$this` variable in `usort` that answer / question is quite different

Comment: How exactly is it different? You want to pass `$this->compareByName` as callback to `usort`, right? Then it's exactly the same answer. – If that's not what you're asking, please clarify.